# Errors on running a sample PCL code on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to run a sample PCL code just to start developing PCL on Visual Studio (2017) on my Windows 10. I followed the guides here: http://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2016/07/set-up-visual-studio-to-use-all-in-one.html

As suggested in their blog post, I downloaded the all-in-one 64bit installer from here: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases/tag/pcl-1.8.1rc1

While I followed all steps, they didn't have a link to a property sheet for PCL 1.8.1 (where can I find it?)

Anyways, when I try to compile my project (no errors on editor), I get 3 link errors as below. How can I run a sample PCL code in Visual Studio? Please help.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl pcl::console::print(enum pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL,char const *,...)" (?print@console@pcl@@YAXW4VERBOSITY_LEVEL@12@PEBDZZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl pcl::detail::FieldMapper<struct pcl::PointXYZ>::operator()<struct pcl::fields::x>(void)" (??$?RUx@fields@pcl@@@?$FieldMapper@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@detail@pcl@@QEAAXXZ)  PCLViewer   c:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PCLViewer\PCLViewer\Source.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl pcl::PLYReader::readHeader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct pcl::PCLPointCloud2 &,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> &,int &,int &,unsigned int &,int)" (?readHeader@PLYReader@pcl@@UEAAHAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEAUPCLPointCloud2@2@AEAV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@AEAV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@7@AEAH4AEAIH@Z)  PCLViewer   c:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PCLViewer\PCLViewer\Source.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl pcl::PLYReader::read(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct pcl::PCLPointCloud2 &,class Eigen::Matrix<float,4,1,0,4,1> &,class Eigen::Quaternion<float,0> &,int &,int)" (?read@PLYReader@pcl@@UEAAHAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEAUPCLPointCloud2@2@AEAV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@AEAV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@7@AEAHH@Z)    PCLViewer   c:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PCLViewer\PCLViewer\Source.obj   1   
Error   LNK1120 3 unresolved externals  PCLViewer   c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\PCLViewer\x64\Debug\PCLViewer.exe    1
```

Comment: Are you able to build your project now ?

Comment: Yes, I eventually did. However, I have to run the .exe manually.